# Conditional entropy of a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, information-theory, entropy

Say I have a multivariate normal distribution as in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions), I know the following:

- $x_1$ conditioned on $x_2=a$ is also normally distributed with a new covariance matrix that is independent of $a$.
- The Entropy of a normally distributed variable is a function of the determinant of its covariance (and not its mean).
- Conditioning cannot increase Entropy in expectation, i.e. $\mathcal H(x_1\vert x_2)= \mathbb{E}_{x_2}\left(H(x_1\vert x_2=a)\right) \leq \mathcal H(x_1) $

Is it possible to conclude that for an N-dimensional $x$ partitioned as such, conditioning never increases Entropy, even for each specific realization of $x_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've said, $x_1$ conditioned on $x_2=a$ is normally distributed with a constant covariance matrix. Hence $h(x_1 | x_2 = a)$ is the differential entropy of that (conditioned) normal, hence it's constant (does not depend on $a$).

Hence $$h(x_1| x_2 ) = \int f_{x_2}(a) h(x_1 | x_2 = a) \, da = h(x_1 | x_2 = a) $$

and then $h(x_1 | x_2 = a) \le h(x_1)$ for any $a$. Of course, this is not true in general.

Comment: What do you mean not true in general?

Comment: I mean that it's not true that "conditioning never increases entropy, even for each specific realization of $x_2$?" It's true for join normal